# Fresh install, nothing clickable, 16.04 LTS

Tags: 16.04

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 16.04 LTS parallel to my Win 10 installation.

Ubuntu is installed after Windows on a seperate HDD. Both installations are in "Legacy mode". This all works fine, if I set the Boot Hdd to the new Ubuntu installation, Grub Gives me the option to Boot to Ubuntu or Win10.

When i Boot into Ubuntu I put in my Password at the login screen and from there on i can't do anything. The desktop looks fine but i can not klick anything (the mouse is movable, and password input on login screen worked) . Also i noticed the system icons in top right are missing.

Any ideas how to fix this?

PS: Installation files were also checked for errors and installation usb stick checked for faulty blocks.

Comment: the launchbar(startbar) isnt visible either?
can you run nautilus through the terminal? ctrl + alt + t then type nautilus, or alt + f2 then type nautilus

Answer (score 0):

Check if your display manager(lightdm or gdm) are up and running from your terminal. You can get into terminal mode using `Ctrl + Alt + F1`. Check status of lightdm or gdm using

```
service lightdm status
```

or

```
service gdm status
```

You can try restarting the service using `service <name> restart`.